# I'm trying to get my program to create a file which will save an input, but I don't want it to appear twice. (Python)

Tags: python

The code I am using is:

```
i=0
f= open("username list.txt", "a+")
for i in range(i+1):
    user=input("Enter your Pokémon Go username to continue.")
    if user != i:
        f.write(user)
    print("Welcome,", user)
f.close()
```

and when the file gets made and appended, if the input is the same, i.e. "hello", it saves again in the file, like this:

```
hellohello
```

which I don't want to happen. I thought I should do some kind of verification for whether or not the input is already in the file, and ask the user whether they want to put their name into the file. What should I do??

P.S: I would also like the different names to be seperated, either by a new line or a comma.

Comment: for clarification, when i said when the input is the same, i meant that if the user's input is already present in the file.

Comment: I would think avoiding txt format would be the best. Because as you progress you would end up having to read the entire file line by line to find where a particular piece of data is stored. Consider JSON? that way you have key-value associations that allow for much easier searching. And easier checking if a value already exists.https://stackabuse.com/reading-and-writing-json-to-a-file-in-python/

Comment: i will change that and see if it helps.

Comment: this is the rest of my code. i was attempting to make a Pokemon Go Pokedex for myself, and when i closed the GUI the choices didn't stay:

Comment: `pokédb = []
master = Tk()
master.geometry("500x500")
is_checked1 = IntVar()
is_checked2 = IntVar()
is_checked3 = IntVar()
`

Comment: and the rest of it cause it didnt fit;

Comment: `Checkbutton(master, text="001: Bulbasaur", onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, variable=is_checked1).grid(row=0, sticky=W)
Checkbutton(master, text="002: Ivysaur", onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, variable=is_checked2).grid(row=1, sticky=W)
Checkbutton(master, text="003: Venasaur", onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, variable=is_checked3).grid(row=2, sticky=W)
if is_checked1.get():
    pokédb.append("001(r)")
if is_checked2.get():
    pokédb.append("002(r)")
if is_checked3.get():
    pokédb.append("003(r)")
database=Button(master, text="Check current database", command=print(pokédb))

Comment: You can add the rest of your code in the question. Please do that instead of in the comments.

Comment: ok i give up with this place i keep pressing enter and it sends the message.

Comment: im new bro i suck at this thanks for help

Comment: i also plan to have pictures with the checkboxes soon. dont know how though.

Answer (score 0):

The most basic and easiest way to do this is to open it in read mode to begin with, separate them through lines and do a basic `if x in y` iteration to see if its already there.

Example:

```
with open("username list.txt", "r") as usernames:
    username_list = usernames.read().splitlines() # .readlines() doesn't always work in my experience, but you're welcome to try it.

i=0
with open("username list.txt", "a+") as f
    for i in range(i+1):
        user=input("Enter your Pokémon Go username to continue.")
        if user != i and user not in username_list:
            f.write(user+"\n") # Make sure you add the new line here otherwise the system wont work.
        print("Welcome,", user)
```

With using this, make sure that `username list.txt` is rather reset/deleted before using or manually put the usernames are on new lines.

Answer (score -1):

The most basic way to do this would be to read the file manually before writing the name and check for a duplicate name before writing the code.

You will need to use `seek`.

```
i= 10
f= open("username_list.txt", "a+")
for i in range(i+1):
    f.seek(0)
    duplicate_found = False
    user=input("Enter your Pokémon Go username to continue.")
    if user != i:
        for name in f:
            if user == name[:-1]:
                duplicate_found = True
                break;
        if not duplicate_found:
            f.write(user+"\n")
    print("Welcome,", user)
f.close()
```

Or instead, you can optimize your program by also keeping the information in memory with collections like `dict`.

Comment: you didn't define name, so the file remained empty.

Comment: I edited the code. Note that `[:-1]` is used to trim trailing `\n`(newline).